# Mutagen: Importing Artwork From URL

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started coding Python a few days ago. I'm still a noob but I'm familiar with other languages so I'm learning quick. I need help with this script I'm writing. I'm using Mutagen to tag m4a files but I'm having issues with saving artwork from a url.
(**Python Version 3.7.4**)

Mutagen Api: https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mp4.html

Below is code that works but it only works for local images. I need to be able to do the same thing but with an image from a url: https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music123/v4/e3/4a/e6/e34ae621-5922-140d-7db0-f6ce0b44d626/19UMGIM78396.rgb.jpg/1400x1400bb.jpg.

```html
from mutagen.mp4 import MP4, MP4Cover
from time import sleep
from os import listdir, getcwd
import datetime
import requests
import urllib.request
.....MORECODE HERE......

with open('artwork.jpg', "rb") as f:
    currentfile["covr"] = [
        MP4Cover(f.read(), imageformat=MP4Cover.FORMAT_JPEG)
    ]
```

Now below is the code I have right now but Python keeps crashing every time I run it. I tried a couple different methods but I can't seem to figure it out. It has to be fairly simple for someone experienced with Python. I tried this already (didn't work) [Python Mutagen: add cover photo/album art by url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301256/python-mutagen-add-cover-photo-album-art-by-url). I think it might be for an older version of Python. Any ideas?

```
        from mutagen.mp4 import MP4, MP4Cover
        from time import sleep
        from os import listdir, getcwd
        import datetime
        import requests
        import urllib.request
        .....MORE CODE HERE.....
        fd = urllib.request.urlopen("https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music123/v4/e3/4a/e6/e34ae621-5922-140d-7db0-f6ce0b44d626/19UMGIM78396.rgb.jpg/1400x1400bb.jpg")
        with open(fd, "rb") as f:
            currentfile["covr"] = [
                MP4Cover(f.read(), imageformat=MP4Cover.FORMAT_JPEG)
            ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> File "mutagen.py", line 11, in  with open(fd, "rb") as f:
>   TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not HTTPResponse

You might consider something as follows:

```
url_artwork="https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music123/v4/e3/4a/e6/e34ae621-5922-140d-7db0-f6ce0b44d626/19UMGIM78396.rgb.jpg/1400x1400bb.jpg"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_artwork,"local.jpg")    
with open("local.jpg", "rb") as f:
        currentfile["covr"] = [
            MP4Cover(f.read(), imageformat=MP4Cover.FORMAT_JPEG)
        ]
```

Comment: That did it! I added import os and the line os.remove("local.jpg") afterwards and it did exactly what I needed. You're a live saver. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. Keep going. Python is pretty straightforward to learn. Thx for the feedback.