# How define the command name for key bindings?

Tags: python

I did simple key bindings, tried to add the shortcut for some command in Sublime Text 3 and to finish the process I had to define the name of the command using the console. After I typed:

```
sublime.commands_log(True)
```

I got the error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'commands_log'
```

I'm not good enough with a Python language yet and I'll really appreciate someone's help to fix this issue.

Comment: There is no function inside sublime module. Check name "commands_log".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969726/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-urlopen)

Answer (score 2):

It is `log_commands` not `commands_log`

Try this:

```
sublime.log_commands(True)
```