# How to read in url in python and then print each URL on the website?

Tags: python, shell, urllib

I am trying to figure out how to only read in each line that is a url from a website, every time I run the code I get the error:

> AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'

My code is below

```
import os
import subprocess
import urllib

datasource = urllib.urlopen("www.google.com")

while 1:
        line = datasource.readline()
        if line == "": break
        if (line.find("www") > -1) :
                print (line)


li = ['www.apple.com', 'www.google.com']
os.chdir('..')
os.chdir('..')
os.chdir('..')
os.chdir('Program Files (x86)\\LinkChecker')

for s in li:
    os.system('Start .\linkchecker ' + s)
```

Comment: are you using python 3.x or 2.7 ?

Comment: afaik urllib.urlopen is python2 ... in python3 try `urllib.request.urlopen`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems python3X, so you should use

```
urllib.request.urlopen
```

Comment: Must be `datasource = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.google.com")` (`urllib.request.urlopen` does not add `"http://"`)

Comment: removed that part. OP will understand that once it works :)

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple example.

This works in Python 3.2 and greater.

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.apple.com") as url:
    r = url.read()
print(r)
```

For reference, go through this question. [Urlopen attribute error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969726/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-urlopen).

Answer (score 0):

The **AttributeError** was because it should be `urllib.request.urlopen` instead of `urllib.urlopen`.

Apart from the `AttributeError` mentioned in the question, I faced 2 more errors.

1. **ValueError**: unknown url type: 'www.google.com'

   **Solution**: Rewrite the line defining `datasource` as follows where the `https` part is included:

   `datasource = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.google.com")`
2. **TypeError**: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
   in the line ' if (line.find("www") > -1) :`.

**The overall solution code is:**

```
import os
import urllib

datasource = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.google.com")

while 1:
        line = str(datasource.read())
        if line == "": break
        if (line.find("www") > -1) :
                print (line)

li = ['www.apple.com', 'www.google.com']
os.chdir('..')
os.chdir('..')
os.chdir('..')
os.chdir('Program Files (x86)\\LinkChecker')

for s in li:
    os.system('Start .\linkchecker ' + s)
```