# how to call api from python, giving syntax error saying - "Invalid syntax"

Tags: python

how to call api from python, giving syntax error saying - "Invalid syntax". getting error at response variable
python version. - 3.6.4
code

```
import urllib
response = urllib.urlopen('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/5564409/feeds.json?results=2')
print response.read()
```

Comment: error - AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'

Comment: That's not a syntax error.

Comment: Have to work with Python v3+. Example + Documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3969809/9896970