# Python: Upload file to Google Cloud Storage using URL

Tags: python, file-upload, google-cloud-platform

I have a URL `(https://example.com/myfile.txt)` of a file and I want to upload it to my bucket `(gs://my-sample-bucket)` on Google Cloud Storage.

What I am currently doing is:

1. Downloading the file to my system using the requests library.
2. Uploading that file to my bucket using python function.

Is there any way I can upload the file directly using the URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transfer file from URL to Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54235721/transfer-file-from-url-to-cloud-storage)

Answer (score 1):

You can use urllib2 or requests library to get the file from HTTP, then your existing python code to upload to Cloud Storage.  Something like this should work:

```
import urllib2
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()

filedata = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/myfile.txt')
datatoupload = filedata.read()

bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-id-here')
blob = Blob("myfile.txt", bucket)
blob.upload_from_string(datatoupload)
```

It still downloads the file into memory on your system, but I don't think there's a way to tell Cloud Storage to do that for you.

Comment: Can you pls suggest same solution in ruby as well. I am new to it and looking for same solution in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this, using a [Cloud Storage Transfer](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/) job, but depending on your use case, it may be worth doing or not. You would need to [create a transfer job](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/transferJobs/create) to [transfer a URL list](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-url-list).

I marked this question as duplicated from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54235721/transfer-file-from-url-to-cloud-storage/54237965).