# Uploading a remote file directly into Google Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I wonder if one can upload a remote file into Google Storage without downloading it first into local storage. Basically what I would like to do is to pass a URL to the storage client and wait until it pulls the file. Thanks!

Comment: I found this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54235721/transfer-file-from-url-to-cloud-storage) to yours, basically the answer mentions that transferring URLs into GCS is possible through the [Cloud Transfer](https://cloud.google.com/products/data-transfer/).This solution is targeted towards a situation with millions of URLs that need to become GCS objects.Another option is writing a job that pumps an incoming stream from reading a URL into a write stream to GCS and running that somewhere in the Google Cloud close to the bucket.

Comment: Can you detail more your use case? Are you on a website? What mean "local storage" for you? A server? your local environment?

Comment: Basically I'm running an app on a vm and I would like to upload some files from a third party directly to GS without downloading it first. Hence local storage would mean storage of the VM. Sorry if this was not clear enough.

Comment: I really think that is not possible upload the files directly to Google Cloud Storage without downloading it first :(  maybe using code you can achieve this.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I am trying to do the same thing.  Closest I have been able to come is downloading it locally into a folder that uses GSFUSE. 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse 
It's still downloading locally but that local server is actually a Google Computer Engine (Google VM).  So the compute engine and GSFUSE directory (which is a Google Cloud Storage bucket) are on the same private google network.

Comment: hey @fred I came to use GSFUSE which is quite impressive in my opinion. If set up correctly, it works like a charm. I mounted a bucket and used it as local file system. You might want to keep an eye on the key differences between GSFUSE and a POSIX file system (concurrency was a bit of an issue for me) and on the pricing as well. So I recommend this, it worked almost perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a google colaboratory instance to do this. You can download a file to the instance and then save it to your drive (though you have to ["mount" the drive](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb) first). Then, you can save file from the instance to your drive. While this is still a 2-step process, it at least avoids having to transfer files to your local machine