# Directly download from a link and upload file to GCS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-cloud-platform, sdk, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to download a MP4 file directly and store on Google bucket. We have a use-case to get a file URL to download and upload it on cloud. However, since file size can be more than 1 GB, it is not feasible to download in local storage first and then upload the file to cloud bucket. We are specifically looking for google cloud storage to upload files and solution should be specific to same.

Some Ref doc we found but does not look like the feasible solution as it uploads file from local storage not directly from link.

https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-storage/latest/Google/Cloud/Storage.html

https://www.mydatahack.com/uploading-and-downloading-files-in-s3-with-ruby/

Comment: Can you check this [StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54242289/18265570) once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage does not offer compute features. That means you cannot directly load an object into Cloud Storage from a URL. You must fetch the object and then upload it into Cloud Storage.